# How can I make my prisoners leave their cell?

Tags: prison-architect

[image]
My prisoners are stuck in their cell block/individual cells. One left his cell to go to the shower but that is connected to the cell block. None of them will leave to go eat, work, etc. They are not blocked by anything. I have not hindered them in any way to entering the other rooms. I have tried having a guard escort them back to the cell they are already in but that does nothing. I have tried removing walls. I am not sure what else to try.

Comment: What does your regime look like?
Did you brand your canteen as "canteen"? Every room needs to be branded. A picture of your prison could also help.

Comment: Everything is labelled and my regime is all set. And they all have access to the rooms. I was thinking maybe the button that send them to their cell willingly is glitched? I am not sure. I used it but then I turned it off. It is not blinking.

Comment: I agree, a screenshot of what's going on would help immensely. Are the cell doors opening at meal times/free time etc? Is a guard available to open the door to the cell block? Did your prisoners all simultaneously get themselves lockdown punishment somehow? It's hard to give a solution unless we know as much as possible.

Comment: All the doors are open and there are three guards available. Hold on I will get one.

Comment: ok there is an image

Comment: Maybe there in lockdown? Do you have solitary cells?

Comment: [Potentially related](http://steamcommunity.com/games/233450/announcements/detail/2127111359838547662). Does everything magically work now?

Comment: Nope still stuck. Yes I have solitary cells but they are not in lockdown. I have no clue. I must start again.

Comment: Check that all the walls are filled in and there are no blanks, I've found that if there are blanks are some places that don;t have foundations it can either lock the prisoners in their room, or let them escape, depending on difficulty. Also, make sure you are running the latest version

Comment: Or possibly they're sentenced to solitary but there are no available cells yet, so they're sitting in cuffs waiting to be transported.

Answer (score 2):

Try to check your deployment area, you might have assigned the way out as staff only.

Answer (score 2):

Look at what areas are maked as. i had this problem because one of my main halways was marked Medium only so my high risk guys would do nothing else. had to swithc back to shared. worked fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

It's the outside you must of accidentally set the outside as a staff only area